# get_registered_nav_menus() is empty when its callad in the hook plugins_loaded

Tags: wordpress, menu, nav, redux-framework

I'm trying to get the registered nav menus in my plugin. As I'm using Redux Framework, I'm inside the hook `plugins_loaded`. So the problem is the `get_registered_nav_menus` function returns an empty array.

This is the reduced case:

```
 function lmm_reduxbug($defaults = array()) {
      var_dump(get_registered_nav_menus());
 }

 add_action('plugins_loaded', 'lmm_reduxbug', 14);
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using the 'after_setup_theme' hook? I think the menu's might not have been loaded on 'plugins_loaded'.

Comment: Or maybe 'init'? You can view the hook execution process here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Answer (score 0):

You may try [`get_nav_menu_locations`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_nav_menu_locations/) instead, worked for me.